# Error message in R using ggplot library: Found object is not a position

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am relatively new user and using R in Rstudio for data visualization.

I want to graph a frequency table piped from the gss_sm data frame:

```
rel_by_region <- gss_sm %>%
group_by(bigregion, religion) %>%
summarize(N = n()) %>%
mutate(freq = N / sum(N),
       pct = round((freq*100), 0))`


p <- ggplot(rel_by_region, aes(x = bigregion, y = pct, fill = religion))
p + geom_col(position = "dodge2") +
  labs(x = "Region",y = "Percent", fill = "Religion") +
  theme(legend.position = "top")`
```

The following error message is shown:

> Found object is not a position

Anyone an idea what I missed here? The ggplot library was installed.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a typo in your `position` argument. It is "dodge" and not "dodge2"

Comment: Thanks! I am working with a ggplot extension described by Kieran Healy in his manuscript in data visualization and he uses dodge2,

Comment: http://socviz.co/workgeoms.html#continuous-variables-by-group-or-category

Comment: The solution is: The "dodge2" argument is not part of the released version of ggplot2 yet,  it's in the development version of ggplot2, Using dodge2 puts the sub-categories side-by-side within groups. To install it you can do

devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the wrong version of ggplot2 package being used.
A google search shows that the most recent release ggplot2 2.2.1 was in 2016, according to https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/releases.

While the "dodge2" position was not introduced until July 2017.
https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/commits/7d0549a03e5ea08c27c768e88d5717f18cb4a5ce/R/position-dodge2.r

Manually installing the dev version package should solve the problem.

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
```

Good luck.